# Как в Android Studio отключить автоматическое форматирование (отступы) при копировании части кода из файла в файл?

Tags: android-studio, настройки, форматирование-кода

Как в Android Studio отключить автоматическое форматирование (отступы, стиль) при копировании части кода (строк) из файла в файл, чтобы код жестоко не переформатировался под управлением настроек системы, а оставался таким же, каким был при копировании, или, хотя бы, сделать это форматирование адекватным форматированию, которое имеется в целевом файле?

P.S. Очень хотелось бы полностью отключать это насильственное, порой, очень нелепое автоформатирование кода. Чтобы код не трогали, а позволяли вставлять его таким "каков он есть". Я понимаю, что автоформат кода можно под себя настроить, но ситуации бывают разные... И файлы писаны бывают по-разному... в разном стиле... Одна настройка может не подходить под разные файлы, например, просто писанные разными программистами, разными стилями... И попавшими в одну, общую сборку... Ну вы меня поняли. 
Неужто существующий механизм всех устраивает?

Мне мешают вот эти настройки. Где-то они в тему, а где-то в проблему)
Если отступы обнулить, то любой код вставляется с отсутствием отступов, что еще хуже! )))

Это всё касается не только Java, но больше даже с XML проблем!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Форматирование это что? Отступы?

Comment: Да. Спасибо! Отступы! Подправлю для ясности вопрос!

Comment: Что-то я запутался. Вот я беру в интернет код и вставляю его в АС. Он вставляется так, как есть. Никакого автоформатирования не происходит, пока я сам его не сделаю. О какой автоформатировании речь?

Comment: Эникейщик! Я дополнил вопрос. Посмотри пожалуйста! )

Comment: Все равно непонятно. Вот я вставляю себе в код скопированый текст и все отступы сохраняются, как тебе и хочется. Покажи пару скринов, где у тебя происходит автоформатирование после вставки.

Answer (score 1):

После вставки текста нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Отступы автоматически подправятся под структуру кода.

Comment: Плюс я поставил Но пока не принял, вдруг, кто ответит на главный вопрос Как полностью отключить это насильственное, порой, очень нелепое автоформатирование кода при копировании. Чтобы код не трогали, а позволяли копировать так "как есть". Я понимаю, что настройку можно под себя настроить, но ситуации бывают разные... И файлы писаны бывают по-разному... в разном стиле... Одна настройка может не подходить под разные файлы, просто писанные разными программистами, разными стилями...