# Перестали отображаться отступы когда сделал binding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

Когда сделал binding

```
 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding.root)
.
```

Перестали отображаться

```
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/context_viewMainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ilyamart.findphone.MainActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

В чём проблема ?

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893035)

Comment: Спасибо, за комментарий , но это не то )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поменять

```
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
```

НА

```
 android:paddingRight="25dp"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
```